# Sending files over Samba with command line

Tags: command-line, samba, scp, file-transfer

I was wondering if there is a way to use Samba to send items to a client machine via the command line (I need to send the files from the Samba server). I know I could always use `scp` but first I was wondering if there is a way to do it with Samba. Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`smbclient`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smbclient.1.html), a program that comes with Samba:

```
$ smbclient //server/share -c 'cd c:/remote/path ; put local-file'
```

There are many flags, such as `-U` to allow the remote user name to be different from the local one.

On systems that split Samba into multiple binary packages, you may have the Samba servers installed yet still be missing `smbclient`. In such a case, check your package repository for a package named `smbclient`, `samba-client`, or similar.

Comment: I keep getting `Connection to [IP] failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)`

Comment: When I wrote `//server` above, I mean what you are calling the client machine, which in this case is *acting* as a server. It needs to have a folder or drive shared via SMB for this to work.

Comment: Oh... that won't really work for me. I guess I'll just use `scp`. Thanks anyway though!

Comment: @fleebow8: You can install a third-party SCP server on the client machines, but you can't right-click a folder in Windows Explorer and say "Share"?

Comment: I have a specific project I'm doing where I want everything to be automatic.

Comment: @fleebow8: Once a share is established, it stays established. Any process that can install an SCP server can enable an SMB share. In fact, the latter is easier, since it's built into Windows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24305/discussion-between-fleebow8-and-warren-young).

Comment: how would you `put` a `local-file` that wasn't in your current directory?

Comment: When trying programatically perform ops, //hostname/sharename are mandatory parts of  having an address to connect with the smb server, after these two directories of upload would be considered e.g.: //hostname/sharename/parentFolder/childFolder, to perform CD on directories on a string one must remove hostname and sharename initially.

Answer (score 36):

curl supports the `smb` v1 protocol [since v7.40](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTg4MzI):

```
curl --upload-file /path/to/file.ext  -u 'DOMAIN\Username' smb://172.16.17.52/ShareName/
```

SMB v1 is not available by default in Windows anymore so this won't work with current Windows shares in their default configuration.

Comment: This worked great for me: `curl --upload-file /home/me/local_file.txt --user "OurWindowsDomain\UserName:thePassword" smb://172.16.17.52/ShareName/Path/To/Remote/Dir`. I got a list of all the available sharenames with `smbclient -L //172.16.17.52 -U UserName%thePassword -W OurWindowsDomain`

Comment: this is perfect!

Comment: Can I use `curl --upload-file` and create a new directory on samba? `--create-dirs` doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

Really working will be this:

`$ smbclient //server/share -c 'cd c:/remote/path ; put local-file remote-file'`

local-file  - file from local machine

remote-file - copy to this file on remote machine

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I found is using **smbget**

```bsh
smbget smb://PATH/TO/FILE/test.txt
```

If authentication is needed (if password is not provided, it will prompt for password):

```bsh
smbget smb://PATH/TO/FILE/test.txt -U "john@example.com%myPassword"
```

You can also specify where to save the file and the name of the file after copy:

```bsh
smbget smb://PATH/TO/FILE/test.txt -U "john@example.com%myPassword" -o /LINUX/PATH/remote_test_file
```

Answer (score 2):

I did lot of research and finally I was successful to transfer file using below command through shell file in one shot.

```
smbclient -m smb2 '//xx.xxx.xxx.xx/share1/' -U domxyz/xyz%password123 -c 'cd "FOLDER 1/FOLDER 2/" ; put FILE1.xlsx'
```

Answer (score 1):

`smbclient Version 4.9.5-Debian` and `curl 7.64.0` didn't work for me (`Linux kali 4.19.0-kali4-amd64`)

This did:

```
smbmap -H server -u username -p password --upload local-filename share\\remote-filename
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Another way if the share is already mounted by *fuse*

If you are running some desktop with shares already mounted by *nautilus*, *caja* or any other *file manager*, you could be using *fuse* (instead of *smbclient*).

If so, you may find some mountpoints at:

```
ls -l /run/user/$UID/gvfs/
drwx------ 1 charlie charlie 0 Feb  2 10:04 smb-share:server=hostname,share=documents
```

Yes this is a *mountpoint*!

```
df -h /run/user/$UID/gvfs/*
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail  Use% Mounted on
gvfsd-fuse      16.2T  3.6T  12.6T   59% /run/user/1000/gvfs
```

And you could use it as a regular filesystem.

```
cp $HOME/myfile \
    /run/user/$UID/gvfs/smb-share:server=hostname,share=documents/destpath/
```