# how can we copy a file from linux to windows shared drives password less

Tags: linux, windows, scp

We have a linux system and windows and need to transfer file to a shared location \local\insurance\input password less

We have file.txt in linux and we need to copy to windows shared paths.

Is there any syntax to do that , i tried below command and didnt worked

```
scp file.txt admin@insurancepp01:\\local\insurance\input
```

Please any suggestion or reference links for UNC paths

I tried `curl --upload-file dummy.txt  --user "abc\admin" smb:\\local\insurance\input`.

I cannot install smbclient as we have limitation and need to discuss with admin team.

Comment: `man smbclient` - why are you using SCP (SSH) to access a whole different protocol (CIFS) is beyond me. Do you also use a web browser to open Windows File Shares? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/206416

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending files over Samba with command line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206415/sending-files-over-samba-with-command-line)

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov .. Thanks a lot for the reply , but it cant help me though as the example is between windows to windows, as in my case linux to windows shared drive

Comment: `smbclient` is a **Linux (Unix) command**.

Comment: Well, discuss it with your admin, as `smbclient` is **the tool you need**. There are no other options AFAIK. curl will not work for you.

Comment: Forget `scp`, that is useful for Unix2Unix file transfer as you need an ssh server on the other side (and not a WIndows share). Check other answers above, Samba is your friend.

Comment: your curl command is almost fine, just replace: `smb:\\local\insurance\input` --> `smb://local/insurance/input`

Comment: @redseven . I just updated the command and getting below error ::::    "  curl: (1) Protocol smb not supported or disabled in libcurl "

Comment: @redseven Any suggestion pls with the above error

Comment: What is your curl version? smb is supported since v7.4 (released in 2015). What distribution do you use?